# Understand JSON result

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my code I have to analyse JSON objects. I use a small function set:

```
    visit = function(object) {
        if (isIterable(object)) {
            forEachIn(object, function (accessor, child) {
                visit(child);
            });
        }
        else {
            var value = object;
            console.log(value);
        }
    };

    forEachIn = function(iterable, functionRef) {
        for (var accessor in iterable) {
            functionRef(accessor, iterable[accessor]);
        }
    };

    isIterable = function(element) {
        return isArray(element) || isObject(element);
    };

    isArray =  function(element) {
        return element.constructor == Array;
    };

    isObject = function(element) {
        return element.constructor == Object;
    };
```

If I throw now a JSON Object to the visit function, it give me just the value to the console. But I expected the key/value combination. Example:

Code throw

```
aa03ddbffe59448fb8a56f6b80e650053
```

But I expect

```
uuid: aa03ddbffe59448fb8a56f6b80e650053
```

Is there anything I misunderstand?

Comment: Lets see the ___JavaScript  Object___ you're testing this on.

Comment: You're only logging one `value`. How would that output two values?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `value` variable must contain a different type from what you're expecting. You could try putting a breakpoint on that line of code and inspecting the object to check what it is. You're expecting the `value` variable to contain an object with a single `uuid` property, but it looks to me like the variable actually just contains a `string`.